# android read barcode value from textbox value

Tags: android, textbox, barcode

I want to make a small application that lets the user enter a barcode number into a text box. Then he can scan a barcode and if the barcode number in the text box matches the barcode scanned, a small message is displayed, saying 'matched'.

For some reason the barcode I enter does not find a match even though I have given the exact barcode number that I am scanning. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 
    //retrieve scan result 
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
      //String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
        doSomething();
    }
    else{ 
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        toast.show(); 
    }
}
//Output a message if the barcode matches the code stated in 'scanContent'
public void doSomething(){
    if (codeNumber.getText() == contentTxt.getText()) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We have a match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOES NOT MATCH!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: which library are you using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you come from the world of C. Welcome friend.

In Java, one does not simply compare two String instances, since String is an object, not a primitive type.

By using the `==` operand, you're comparing both string objects' addresses in memeory. Since in your case they're not the same object, the result is `FALSE`.

To compare the values, use [String.equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
if (contentTxt.getText().toString().equals(codeNumber.getText().toString())) {
```

Comment: Hey, i have indeed come from the C language. I tried what you stated above but i am still getting the "Does not match" toast.

Comment: This is a whole new problem. The strings are indeed different. Please assign a variable for codeNumber.getText() as well as contentTxt.getText() and debug and check the values.

Comment: Actually, i had to swap it around a little. Now works perfectly! Thanks heaps! 'if (contentTxt.getText().toString().equals(codeNumber.getText().toString())) {'